# access series of arrays with a loop

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I need to access some arrays one by one by their name but because they will be called one by one I can't access them by directly calling their names.
What I have is something like this :

```
var cat1 : []
var cat2 : []
var cat3 : []
var cat4 : []
var cat5 : []

for () {
"Here there is some code that is different based on which array I'm dealing with"
}
```

I don't know how to write the "for loop" for this purpose.

Comment: Create an array of arrays: `var allCats = [cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, cat5]` and make an outer loop iterate over `allCats`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of arrays:

```
let cats = [cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, cat5]

for cat in cats {

}
```

This is suspicious though. What exactly are you trying to do?